# Parameterise Jenkins pipeline use different workflow

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have one project where we have different Jenkins files for different workflows. I need to implement new requirements for this project Jenkins files.

My requirements are like this,

1- I have a set of common parameters that will be used for two workflows. I have one choice based parameter which has four choices. If the parameter has choices **"A, B, C"** then use the actual workflow already implemented in one Jenkin file 
**(A)** and If the parameter has a choice **"D"** then use the new workflow which is implemented in other Jenkin files **(B)**.

The question is how can I implement this requirement. Should I need to add all parameters in both `Jenkin` files or should I need to create another `Jenkin` file as master and define all parameters in that file and put some conditions over there to call the other Jenkins files on choice-based.

If anyone works on such a requirement or has a good experience to explain the solution, then please write me back with the proper solution. So that I can implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to a) unite your two files into a single one, or b) use a third Jenkinsfile that will trigger either `build job: 'job-A', parameters:` or `build job: 'job-B', parameters:`.

Comment: How could I use the new file for this purpose and how can I mentioned the info there. Any help?